# Concatanate a CDN link list to a file (gulp)

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

I have a list of CDN (or remote) scripts (with full URL). I want to transform this into a concatened file (`all.js`). **Can I do that with gulp?** In other words, is it the right tool?

```
// Does not work (no error, but no file generated)
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/'));
});
```

*I'm new to gulp, I did not found the answer after some search, maybe I don't know how to search or I did not understand gulp goal.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't give you a full answer because I haven't done anything like this, but what I would do, is first download (With a GET request) save it in a temporal folder, and then get every file downloaded with gulp and concat them into one file and if it is just Javascript, uglify it.

But the thing is you need to download it first.

PD: You can use then fs.unlink to delete the temporal files.
PD2: You can download it first using Gulp, Gulp is Node afterall ;)

Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

This answer is taken from here:
http://fettblog.eu/gulp-merge-cdn-files-into-your-pipeline/

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var request = require('request');
var merge = require('merge2');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');

gulp.task('js', function() {

  var jquery = request('http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js') /* 1 */
    .pipe(source('jquery.js'));                                   /* 2 */
  var main = gulp.src('main.js');                                 /* 3 */

  return merge(jquery, main)                                      /* 4 */
    .pipe(buffer())                                               /* 5 */
    .pipe(concat('concat.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})
```

1) We request the latest jQuery version from the jQuery CDN. The request package allows for streaming. What we get in return is a readable stream.

2) We create a valid vinyl file object with vinyl-source-stream. This makes it compatible with Gulp

3) Our main file is selected from the file system as usual

4) The merge2 package allows us to combine both streams

5) The contents of both streams are converted to text buffers so gulp-concat can handle them.

Comment: Please, do not just give away links like that, you can construct a proper response and state your source if needed. The problem is  : what happen if your link become unreachable ? You question is then still the answer ?